# How to create a mask array from the max value of all overlapping arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, max, mask

I have many 2d arrays of the same dimension. Each pixel has a value of 0, 1, or 23. Each array has the values distributed in different locations. I want a max-mask that is the result of overlaying all arrays and taking the max value of each location. I also want a min-mask that does the opposite. Sorry if it's a stupid question... I tried to search but only got the methods to get a single max/min value over the entire array or on a certain axis. Thanks a lot in advance if you could help!

My arrays are large and I will give a simple example here -

```
a = ([[0, 1, 0, 0, 23],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [23, 23, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 23, 0, 1]])
b = ([[23, 1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 23, 1],
      [0, 23, 0, 23, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 0, 23]])
# After some coding, max_mask and min_mask should be:
max_mask = ([[23, 1, 0, 1, 23],
             [1, 0, 0, 23, 1],
             [23, 23, 0, 23, 1],
             [1, 1, 23, 0, 23]])
min_mask = ([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 23, 0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

As I have too many arrays created from generic funtion and they are named like data1985, data1986... data2020, is there a way I can loop through all of them in an easier way?

```
# this is how I create them by reading images
for i in range(1985, 2021):
        globals()[f"data{i}"], globals()[f"geo{i}"], globals()[f"proj{i}"]  = read_tif(r"C:\Users\wqtcl\Desktop\REDD\images/" +str(i)+".tif")
        globals()[f"data{i}"][np.isnan(globals()[f"data{i}"])]=23

# I want something like this (or easier!!)
# initialize array filled with zeros
mask = np.zeros([len(data1985), len(data1985[0])], dtype=int)

# populate array
for i in range(1985, 2021):
    for j in range(len(data1985)):
        for k in range(len(data1985[0])):
            mask[j][k] = max(globals()[f"data{i}"][j][k])

# I got this error though...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18020/2600759678.py in <module>
      6     for j in range(len(data1985)):
      7         for k in range(len(data1985[0])):
----> 8             mask[j][k] = max(globals()[f"data{i}"][j][k])
      9 
     10 print(mask)

TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What library are you using to read the `.tif` images?

Comment: @ddejohn gdal - it's creating 2d arrays. The functions are what I created (e.g. no read_tif in any library)

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to assign variables dynamically like how you're doing. You'd be much better off loading all your `tif` files into a list of arrays. I'm assuming `read_tiff` returns a numpy array?

Comment: @ddejohn thanks for the recommendation but I need my read_tif for various outputs that I do not show here. Sorry if my format is dumb to proceed in these maskings...

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend refactoring your code to stop manipulating the `globals` dict. It is absolutely going to cause headaches, including this one, right now.

Comment: At the very least, use a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: regarding your edit, dynamic variable creation is never a good idea! Read your `tif` images into a list of arrays, then use my solution.

```py
path = r"C:\Users\wqtcl\Desktop\REDD\images/{}.tif"
geo_data = {"data": [], "geo": [], "proj": []}


for i in range(1985, 2021):
    data, geo, proj = read_tif(path.format(i))
    geo_data["data"].append(data)
    geo_data["geo"].append(geo)
    geo_data["proj"].append(proj)


images = np.array(geo_data["data"])
images[np.isnan(images)] = 23.
max_mask = images.max(axis=0)
min_mask = images.min(axis=0)
```

Note that I cannot test this as I do not have `gdal` installed and I don't have a bunch of random `.tif` files with which to test this approach.

### Original solution

Here you go:

```py
In [9]: a
Out[9]:
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0, 23],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [23, 23,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1, 23,  0,  1]])

In [10]: b
Out[10]:
array([[23,  1,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0, 23,  1],
       [ 0, 23,  0, 23,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0, 23]])

In [11]: np.maximum(a, b)
Out[11]:
array([[23,  1,  0,  1, 23],
       [ 1,  0,  0, 23,  1],
       [23, 23,  0, 23,  1],
       [ 1,  1, 23,  0, 23]])

In [12]: np.minimum(a, b)
Out[12]:
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0, 23,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  1]])
```

If you need to do this for more than two arrays, you can initialize a 3D array and call `.max(axis=0)`:

```py
In [15]: c
Out[15]:
array([[23,  0, 23,  1,  1],
       [23, 23,  1,  0, 23],
       [23,  1, 23,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 23,  0]])

In [16]: d
Out[16]:
array([[23,  0,  0, 23, 23],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  0, 23],
       [ 0,  0, 23, 23,  0],
       [ 1,  0, 23, 23,  0]])


In [17]: np.array([a, b, c, d]).max(axis=0)
Out[17]:
array([[23,  1, 23, 23, 23],
       [23, 23,  1, 23, 23],
       [23, 23, 23, 23,  1],
       [ 1,  1, 23, 23, 23]])
```

Comment: what about I have dozens of arrays that I cannot specify in the input? I tried to use a generic name but it didn't work out. I will edit my questions in a sec, if possible, could you please take a look over that? Your answer already helped a lot!!! @ddejohn

Comment: images = np.array([read_tif(path.format(i) for i in range(1985, 2021))]) --> RuntimeError: not a string. Sorry for taking so much of your time... it is giving me errors. Although this test would work print(path.format(1987)). (a missing parenthesis is fixed as well)

Comment: My bad, the `read_tif` function call wasn't closed. Try now, I've edited.

Comment: ah got it... I put the parenthesis in the wrong place. what about this: max_mask = images.max(axis=0) ---- The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). I tried to add .any and .all in possible positions but all returned some sort of errors.

Comment: What exactly does a `read_tif` call return? A numpy array? A tuple? I see in your original code that you're unpacking, sorry I missed that the first time.

Comment: It's array of arrays plus some geo-info wrapped in that bigger array. array([[array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
               [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
               [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
               ...,
               [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
               [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
               [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32),
        (-74.313491204, 0.0089831528411, 0.0, 5.612404400, 0.0, -0.0089831528411),
        'GEOGCS...(saving space here)....AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]'], next one etc...

Comment: so that images[np.isnan(images)] = 23. can't work either

Comment: Mmk, try my most recent edit. Keep in mind I'm working in the dark here as I don't have access to your data to see for myself what we're working with.

Comment: Ahhhh the last edit works!!! Until I do some cumbersome manual overlay to validate, I won't bother you :))) This is really awesome! Thanks a lot for spending time here!!

Comment: validated to work very well without error! Accepted of course! :D